# Service Worker registering, but no events fired

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I try to learn how to use service workers in my web applications. My test setup looks like this:

Browser --https--> apache --http--> tomcat

the apache is forwarding to tomcat with this vhost conf(mydomainname is obfuscated):

```
<VirtualHost test:80>
    ServerName test.mydomainname
    Redirect permanent / https://test.mydomainname
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost test:443>
    ServerAdmin administrator@mydomainname
    ServerName test.mydomainname
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/test-access_log" common
    ProxyPass / http://tomcat.mydomainname:8080/test/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://tomcat.mydomainname:8080/test/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /test /
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile ssl/cert.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/cert.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

I do have a DNS entry on my on-site DNS as well to get to the apache in the first place

Tomcat is serving files as shown here:

```
tomcatcontainer 'test'
  \-index.html
  \-main.js
  \-worker.js
  \-test.png
```

The index looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TEST</title>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        HELLORLD
        <button onclick="doIt()" >TEST</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my main:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator
    .serviceWorker
    .register(
      './worker.js'
    )
    .then(function (reg) {
      console.log('Registration Successful');
    });
}

function doIt(){
    console.log("doIt");
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "./test.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

and the worker:

```
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
   console.log("Service worker installed");
});
self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
   console.log("Service worker activated");
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  console.log("fetch");
});
```

Website is accessible and displays the correct content served with https to the browser. It seems to register the service worker as well("Registration Successful" log is showing up), but as I have understood, as soon as the js file got to the browser, the install event should fire? Unfortunately that is not the case.  Not only that, none of the console.log from the worker.js is printed out. When I check on the application tab of the firefox dev tools I see the worker there, but it says stopped?
[image]
I can start it with clicking the button, but there are still no console logs from inside the worker appearing.

What did I do wrong here?